# bind combobox text

Tags: apache-flex

I have an editable combobox. How can I bind the text the user enters? I can only do binding when the user selects whatever it is they typed in...how can I bind it as they type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

    [Bindable]
    public var boundText:String;

</script>

<TextBox text="@{boundText}" />
```

This will set up a two-way binding so changes to the textbox's text are reflected in boundText, and vice-versa.